# What does mov [ebx+0x18] ecx do?

Tags: assembly, x86

What does this instruction do? 
I don't understand the [ebx+0x18] what is it doing? cos ebx isn't an address it's an register so please help me ^^

Comment: EBX can contain an address...

Comment: is it incrementing the address in ebx ?

Comment: It is accessing the memory address held by `ebx` with an offset of `24`.

Comment: is the offset in byte ?

Comment: @assemblerMan there is no bit addressing, addresses are in bytes and so is the offset.

Comment: You need to understand *indirect addressing* in assembly language. Look it up in your search engine and study it.

Comment: You should seriously consider using an instruction reference.  This is a fairly basic and very common indirect addressing notation.

Comment: an other question, whats the differenc of libc-2.11.2.so or libc.so.6 and which of them gots linked in the memory mapping segment?an other question, whats the differenc of libc-2.11.2.so or libc.so.6 and which of them gots linked in the memory mapping segment?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the instruction is `mov [ebx+0x18], ecx`?

This is Intel syntax, where the square brackets mean that the value inside is being *dereferenced*, as if it were a pointer. In this case, the constant offset `0x18` is added to the value stored in the `ebx` register, and then this is interpreted as a memory address that is then dereferenced.

The instruction therefore copies the value stored in `ecx` into the memory pointed to by `ebx+0x18`.

Note that the actual contents of the `ebx` and `ecx` registers are *not* modified—only the memory at address `ebx+0x18`.

Answer (score 3):

The `mov` instruction is like this:

```
mov <destination>, <source>
```

So to set the register EBX to the same value as ECX, you would have:

```
mov ebx, ecx
```

The brackets around an operand mean to use dereferencing, i.e. look at the address in a particular register, and use that as the source or destination. To set the place in memory *pointed at* by EBX to the value of ECX:

```
mov [ebx], ecx
```

And finally, you can do some basic arithmetics when dereferencing. So, to set the place `0x18` (or 24) bytes forward from the place pointed at by EBX to the value of ECX:

```
mov [ebx + 0x18], ecx
```

Comment: is the 0x18 offset in byte or bits ?

Comment: @assemblerMan Neither. 0x18 is just an offset, so it is just a number that when added to an address, produces an address. As explained `X + O` produces the address given by the sum of *X* and *O* (e.g. 0x100 + 0x18 = 0x118). Now what an address represents in the x86 architecture? a bit, a byte, a word?

Comment: @assemblerMan It is indeed just adding numbers, as Margaret explained. In this case I think it's safe to say addresses refer to *byte* position, thus the byte offset is 24 *bytes* ahead from the place EBX points to.

Comment: an other question, whats the differenc of libc-2.11.2.so or libc.so.6 and which of them gots linked in the memory mapping segment?

Comment: @assemblerMan That is a very much unrelated question … I'm sorry I cannot help you there, because I don't know :)